# Using MSMTP with CodeIgniter email library

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

Has anyone successfully been able to send email using the standard CodeIgniter email library when using msmtp?

I'm running Ubuntu and I've successfully installed and configured MSMTP.  I've been able to send email from the command line and also using the default PHP `mail()` function.

My `application/config/email.php` file looks like this

```
$config = array(
    'protocol' => 'sendmail',
    'mailpath' => '/usr/bin/msmtp -C /etc/msmtp/.msmtprc -t',
    'smtp_host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
    'smtp_user' => 'myemail@gmail.com',
    'smtp_pass' => 'xxxxxxxx',
    'smtp_port' => 587,
    'smtp_timeout' => 30,
    'smtp_crypto' => 'tls',
);
```

But this doesn't work.  If anyone's been successful it would be good to know how you did it.  Ideally I'd like to use CodeIgniter's email library as it has a lot of good functionality that I don't want to have to write myself.

Comment: what is the purpose of using the msmtp instead CI default email library.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "this doesn't work"? Does it error? What is the error that you're getting? And by saying that you were able to send mail via `mail()`, did you mean that `mail()` forwards to your msmtp setup?

Comment: http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/email.html

Answer (score 6):

I was able to send an email through CodeIgniter and msmtp without too much trouble. In my case I used Sendgrid as I encountered authentication issues using msmtp with Gmail and Yahoo. Here's my setup (running on Ubuntu 14.04, php 5.5.9, [Code Igniter latest](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter)):

**msmtp config - */home/quickshiftin/.msmtprc***

```
account sendgrid
host smtp.sendgrid.net
port 587
auth on
tls on
tls_starttls on
tls_trust_file /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
user SendGridUsername
password SendGridPassword
```

**Code Igniter Controller - *application/controller/Tools.php***

```
class Tools extends CI_Controller {

    public function message()
    {
        $this->load->library('email');

        $this->email->from('some-dude@gmail.com', 'Nate');
        $this->email->to('another-dude@gmail.com');

        $this->email->subject('Send email through Code Igniter and msmtp');
        $this->email->message('Testing the email class.');

        $this->email->send();
    }
}
```

**Email Library Config - *application/config/email.php***

```
$config = [
    'protocol' => 'sendmail',
    'mailpath' => '/usr/bin/msmtp -C /home/quickshiftin/.msmtprc --logfile /var/log/msmtp.log -a sendgrid -t',
];
```

**Sending the email via the CLI**

`php index.php tools message`

**Thoughts on your issue**

- Is */etc/msmtp/.msmtprc* readable by your webserver or command line user? Is `/usr/bin/msmtp` executable by said user?
- [`popen`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.popen.php) may be disabled in your PHP environment
- Use [a debugger](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/how-to-debug-in-php) to trace through the call to `CI_Email::_send_with_sendmail` method to determine why it's failing in your case
- If you configure a log file for msmtp as I have you can look there after trying to send through Code Igniter to catch potential issues

Answer (score -2):

My Email config is below:

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed.');
// Mail engine switcher: 'CodeIgniter' or 'PHPMailer'
$config['useragent']        = 'PHPMailer';
// 'mail', 'sendmail', or 'smtp'
$config['protocol']         = 'smtp';
$config['mailpath']         = '/project-folder/sendmail';
$config['smtp_host']        = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$config['smtp_user']        = 'Your Gmail Email';
$config['smtp_pass']        = 'Your Gmail Pass';
$config['smtp_port']        = 587;
// (in seconds)
$config['smtp_timeout']     = 30;  
// '' or 'tls' or 'ssl'                     
$config['smtp_crypto']      = 'tls'; 
// PHPMailer's SMTP debug info level: 0 = off, 1 = commands, 2 = commands and data, 3 = as 2 plus connection status, 4 = low level data output.                      
$config['smtp_debug']       = 0; 
// Whether to enable TLS encryption automatically if a server supports it, even if `smtp_crypto` is not set to 'tls'.                       
$config['smtp_auto_tls']    = false; 
// SMTP connection options, an array passed to the function stream_context_create() when connecting via SMTP.                   
$config['smtp_conn_options'] = array();                 
$config['wordwrap']         = true;
$config['wrapchars']        = 76;
// 'text' or 'html'
$config['mailtype']         = 'html'; 
// 'UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-15', ...; NULL (preferable) means config_item('charset'), i.e. the character set of the site.                  
$config['charset']          = null;                     
$config['validate']         = true;
// 1, 2, 3, 4, 5; on PHPMailer useragent NULL is a possible option, it means that X-priority header is not set at all
$config['priority']         = 3;
// "\r\n" or "\n" or "\r"
$config['crlf']             = "\n";
// "\r\n" or "\n" or "\r"                     
$config['newline']          = "\n";                     
$config['bcc_batch_mode']   = false;
$config['bcc_batch_size']   = 200;
// The body encoding. For CodeIgniter: '8bit' or '7bit'. For PHPMailer: '8bit', '7bit', 'binary', 'base64', or 'quoted-printable'.
$config['encoding']         = '8bit';
```